# How to suppress over-verbose xpath-output?

Tags: xml, shell, xpath

I'm using xpath (as supplied in Mac OS X 10.9 `usr/bin/xpath5.16`) in a shell script to parse some values from an XML file which works really well. However it gives me some verbose output which I don't want to see in my script. I actually only want to store the result (the content of the attribute) in a variable.

```
content=$(xpath ../../AndroidManifest.xml /manifest/@android:versionCode)
echo "$content"
```

After execution the variable `content` indeed contains the content of the attribute, however there is also some verbose output I want to get rid of. Here it is:

```
Found 1 nodes:
-- NODE --

 android:versionCode="38"
```

Note: the "38" at the end of the output originates from the `echo "$content"` line the rest is the output of `xpath`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the solution. Simply append `2>/dev/null` to the command:

```
content=$(xpath ../../AndroidManifest.xml /manifest/@android:versionCode 2>/dev/null)
```

Output:

```
 android:versionCode="38"
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`man xpath`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xpath.1p.html):

```
-q
    Be quiet. Output only errors (and no separator) on stderr.
```

Better use `xpath -q ...` instead of piping all stderr-messages. This will make sure actual *errors* will continue to be printed, but no other status output / node dividers.

Comment: I already found this flag by googling, unfortunately it doesn't apply to the xpath version supplied in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

**-q** did not work for me. Since xpath utulity prints extra output on std-err, just redirect it to /dev/null

```
xpath file.xml  '/foo/bar/text()' 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: See my own response. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Folks to stretch your enthusiasm but look at this output instance of Open Directory Keywords attribute, it's made of text strings which each one is a node in dscl plist output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>dsAttrTypeStandard:Keywords</key>
        <array>
                <string>nelve0jfO</string>
                <string>qPknu6</string>
                <string>cic3-bubcd</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>


 /usr/bin/xpath "//string[.]/text()"
```

Output (console print is 4 lines):

Found 3 nodes:
-- NODE --

nelve0jfO-- NODE --

qPknu6-- NODE --

cic3-bubcd

```
/usr/bin/xpath "//string[.]/text()" 2>/dev/null
```

Output:

nelve0jfOqPknu6cic3-bubcd

Whithout linefeed...

Who knows if its possible to append field delimiter in the query syntax?

Comment: `| grep string | cut -c11- | cut -d'<' -f1 | tr '\n' ';' | rev | cut -c2- | rev`
instead of xpath do the job